# JPA/EclipseLink: disable cascade for certain merge operations?

Tags: jpa, merge, eclipselink, cascade, toplink

I am using EclipseLink 2.3.3. with a data model with about 100 entities.  I have a Java class mapped to each database table using annotations.

I have two use cases to implement.  One is that a new record enters the system that hits about 60-75 of the tables.  For this case, I want merge and persist to cascade, so that I can just merge the top level object and have that cascade to all related entities.

Another use case is that I need to insert a collection of individual objects, often one from each of a bunch of different tables.  In this case I don't want the cascading merge, because I need to have control over the insertions.  If I have cascade enabled, merging the first object might or might not merge the other objects, depending on if or how they are related, so I'd rather explicitly merge each of them.

So essentially, I want cascading merge and persist in one situation, but not another.  So if I include the cascade annotations in the mapped classes, I need to selectively disable the cascading for certain operations; or, if I turn off cascading in the mapped classes, I would like to enable cascading for certain operations.

So far I am not finding any way to selectively turn on or off cascading for a particular operation.  There is a CascadePolicy class but that seems to only be used with queries.  There are dynamic entities, and I was thinking perhaps I could use that to do something like create a dynamic entity from an existing entity and turn off the cascading behavior on that entity's relationships and somehow use that for the merge, but I have not been able to find the right API for that.

So I am wondering if there is a better answer somewhere that I'm overlooking?  Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about what level of control you are after, especially in the case that you mention you want to insert individual objects.  From the sounds of it, cascade merge is exactly what you want for your Entity object tree in the first case for use with the EntityManager.merge.  Merge called on an entity will check if it is new or not, and update or insert as appropriate.  Marking relationships as cascade merge will allow finding new objects and having them inserted.

The second case though where you want to handle individual insertions, why not exclude the cascade persist option on mappings and just call EntityManager.persist on the objects you want to insert?  Persist then will not cascade, so only the entity you call em.persist on will get inserted.  Relationships will be used just to set the foreignkey values - though you might want to leave them nulled out and set them later as part of larger merge calls.  Both sides of bidirectional relationships need to be maintained, and if the other side is exists and doesn't get merged, its relationship changes are not stored.

If that isn't what you want, EclipseLink has native API on the UnitOfWork (the EntityManager essentially wraps a UnitOfWork for transactional work) that allows you to specify the merge policy.  See mergeClone, deepMergeClone and shallowMergeClone on UnitOfWork, which essentially use CASCADE_ALL_PARTS, CASCADE_PRIVATE_PARTS and NO_CASCADE respectively as the merge policies, while the JPA merges use CASCADE_BY_MAPPING.

Comment: Any idea how we can use NO_CASCADE ?

Comment: @Aguid any solution for this yet ?

Comment: Did you try using shallowMergeClone as suggested?